# Why param paramIgnorePrintAreas in ExportAsFixedFormat does not work?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to export `excel` to `pdf`.
I am using C#.

I have a problem with `ExportAsFixedFormat`. My documents have print area (set in Excel application, they work if manual send to print). But it does not work in my program. I set param `paramIgnorePrintAreas` as false, it does not help.

```
public void createXls(){
    ApplicationClass excelApplication = new ApplicationClass();
    Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
    //Worksheet excelWorksheet = null;
    excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;
    excelApplication.Visible = false;

    string paramSourceBookPath = @"C:\Temp\Test.xlsx";
    object paramMissing = Type.Missing;
    string paramExportFilePath = @"C:\Temp\Test.pdf";
    XlFixedFormatType paramExportFormat = XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF;
    XlFixedFormatQuality paramExportQuality = XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard;
    bool paramOpenAfterPublish = false;
    bool paramIncludeDocProps = true;
    bool paramIgnorePrintAreas = false;
    object paramFromPage = Type.Missing;
    object paramToPage = Type.Missing;
    try
    {
        // Open the source workbook.
        excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(paramSourceBookPath,
         false, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
         paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
         paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
         paramMissing, paramMissing);

    // Save it in the target format.
        if (excelWorkBook != null)
        {
            Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Worksheet) excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
            excelWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFormat,
             paramExportFilePath, paramExportQuality,
             paramIncludeDocProps, paramIgnorePrintAreas, paramFromPage,
             paramToPage, paramOpenAfterPublish,
             paramMissing);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //richTextBox1.Text=ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the workbook object.
        if (excelWorkBook != null)
        {
            excelWorkBook.Close(false, paramMissing, paramMissing);
            excelWorkBook = null;
        }

        // Quit Excel and release the ApplicationClass object.
        if (excelApplication != null)
        {
            excelApplication.Quit();
            excelApplication = null;
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to set the print area again, before exporting:

```
excelWorksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "Print_Area";
```

I had a similar problem that was caused, I think, because it was an International version of Excel and this command fix the output format.